# Wordpress Child theme files not overriding

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

From the Wordpress Codex:

> Template Files If you want to change more than just the stylesheet,
>   your child theme can override any file in the parent theme: simply
>   include a file of the same name in the child theme directory, and it
>   will override the equivalent file in the parent theme directory when
>   your site loads. For instance, if you want to change the PHP code for
>   the site header, you can include a header.php in your child theme's
>   directory, and that file will be used instead of the parent theme's
>   header.php.

When I copy and change files from the parent theme into the exact same location in the child theme, one would suspect those changes to reflect from the above text, am I right?
However, the changes do not reflect at all... All I can really do is change style.css and functions.php of the child theme... NOTHING else works as it's supposed to.

I have copied responsive-1240.css from /css/responsive-1240.css into /css/responsive-1240.css

I then made changes in this new file, but they do not reflect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example? We can't see your theme setup.

Comment: Hey mevius, thank you for quick response. I have updated the description.

Comment: That only works for php files, not for functions files, stylesheets and scipts

Answer (score 1):

That only works for php files, not for functions files, stylesheets and scipts
–  [Pieter Goosen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908141/pieter-goosen)

What you need to do is dequeue the stylesheet somehow and requeue it or put the changes in style.css